# JSON.net writing to a file asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, json.net, uwp

I'm writing a UWP application in the IoT Core which needs to write data to a JSON file.

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(project, Formatting.Indented);
string filePath = @"path/to/file.json";

File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
```

When trying to run the program I get an error message saying:

> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. 
>   Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.

I realize that writing to files synchronously is a bad idea but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it asynchronously. How would I go about saving my JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message suggests you can do:

```
Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(filePath, output));
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `File.WriteAllText` you could create a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) object and use the [`WriteAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629.aspx) method.

`File.WriteAllText` is a convenience method that uses a `StreamWriter` internally. The write method here is a synchronous one. And the `StreamWriter` [uses a `FileStream` internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,80ef9c4284b87f77) :-)